# How to check 2 array is same omitting index

Tags: c#, arrays

```cs
using System;

public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] a = {0, 1, 2, 1};
        int[] b = {0, 1, 2, 1};
        int[] c = {0, 1, 1, 2};
        
        bool isSame = a == b && a == c; // This should be true
        
        Console.WriteLine(isSame);
        
        bool isSame2 = true;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++) 
        {
            if (a[i] != b[i]) isSame2 = false;
        }
        
        Console.WriteLine(isSame2); // This is true but I need to compare a to c too
        
        bool isSame3 = true;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++) 
        {
            if (a[i] != b[i] || a[i] != c[i]) isSame3 = false;
        }
        
        Console.WriteLine(isSame3); // This is false, this should be true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `SequenceEqual` for checking element by element for equatlity

```
bool resut1 = a.SequenceEqual(c); // false
bool resut2 = a.OrderBy(x => x).SequenceEqual(c.OrderBy(x => x)); // true
```

Comment: `a.SequenceEqual(c)` this throw `error CS1061: 'int[]' does not contain a definition for 'SequenceEqual' and no accessible extension method 'SequenceEqual' accepting a first argument of type 'int[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: you should add the following 'using System.Linq'

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this line

```
Console.WriteLine(isSame3); // This is false, this should be true
```

is given a result you are not expecting is because a and b arrays are the same. Meanwhile c array is different

```
    int[] a = {0, 1, 2, 1};
    int[] b = {0, 1, 2, 1};
    int[] c = {0, 1, 1, 2};

c[2] => 1;  a[2],b[2] => 2;
c[3] => 2;  a[3],b[3] => 1;
```

Hence the result you are getting is actually correct.

As stated in the comments and by @fubo (only answer at the moment of writing)
when comparing arrays you should first sort.

Either use in built sort or implement some classic eg(Bubble Sort, Selection Sort, Insertion Sort, Merge Sort, Quick sort).